# Files are Missing in the MailCore Code

Tags: xcode, frameworks, mailcore

I am using the MailCore framework and preparing some application based on remail, as I have downloaded open source from the link http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/  but after downloaded I have also run the Scripts update.sh and autogen.sh to get the essential library files. but these files are missing and showing in red color in my project.

- libetpan.framework
- Tests.octest
- libmailcore.a

From where and How can I get these files..or where I am lacking in the process of extraction of liberaries..?
and Please tell me the process of integrating the MailCore in remail application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to use git submodule init and update. But I don't know how remail is structured. You'll want to rewrite it since it's a really bad example of OO code. But, possibly because MailCore is structured way differently now.

I have made the libraries work on the latest XCode and honestly, you're better off changing to the newer libs. Do not base your source code off of ReMail unless you wish to be stuck writing tons of code to work with deprecated methods.

However, MailCore is still awesome. It has been updated, anyone reading this should check it out at libmailcore's site.